# Reloading external files in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, properties, external, reload

I have an application running on Tomcat that relies on a number of external properties files and external Drools DRL files during its execution. Is there a way in which I can monitor these files for changes and reload them when changes are detected without restarting Tomcat?

Thanks

Angus

Comment: please show the code where you currently use those external files. You know about java.util.File.lastModified(), right?

Comment: Hi Olaf, the files are loaded via other config files namely the context.xml. There isn't any programmatic means by which the application loads them.